# Testing Swing applications with JUnit

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a simple mouse-dragging rectangle application which I have to test with JUnit or probably by introducing a mock object. My question is: **Does JUnit provide any swing tests and which of the two options would be easier?**

Answer (score 1):

With such limited information, this question is hard to answer - i.e. what would you mock? JUnit itself does not provide any specific support for Swing. For that you can have a look at [uispec4j](https://github.com/UISpec4J/UISpec4J).

Comment: Please don't just post a link to some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Better? Given the limited amount of information in the question, this is hard to demonstrate. Thanks for the link, though.

Comment: Better I guess. Note that if a question is not in an answerable state, you can also flag it to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit doesn't provide Swing tests. It is a general purpose library/framework for testing.